# Mbedtls slow handshaking

Tags: tls1.2, mbedtls

I'm using mbedTLS on baremetal lwip+stm32f4 system as a Server. TLS working successfully but when I receive the Client Hello message, my receive proccess function; `err = netif->input(p, netif);`  take a 300ms time. I need to reduce this time. How Can I do that ?
This is my config file: https://wtools.io/paste-code/b7kM